# Getting apps to work on Android-x86 with Virtualbox

Tags: windows, crashes, bugs, android-x86, virtualbox

Almost every app, from chrome to gallery simply crash right after launch, and others like maps have bugs that render it unusable (it all goes black and only the search bar and location button are visible).

I'm running it with 2 cores, 2GB of RAM, 8GB of storage and 128MB of VRAM, better specs than many actual android x86 devices out there.

Is this a virtualbox problem or an android x86 problem?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is a problem with the Android-x86 image you've downloaded, or else that the virtual hardware you've set up in Virtualbox doesn't match the configuration the image is expecting. Check which image file you've downloaded, and make sure the configuration matches what's described in the setup instructions.

Comment: I'm using the official 4.4 from androidx86.org and configured the vb as Linux-other

Comment: What config are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any config. I don't use Android-x86, I'm just guessing based on my previous experience of Android porting and other questions we've had here.